# use couchbase-lite 2.5 with javafx application

Tags: javafx-2, couchbase-lite

I developed my javafx application using couchbase-lite 1.3 and it works as expected.

But now, i want to use the N1QL query to retrieve the data from this database.
This is not possible with 1.3 version.
on https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/2.0/index.html i can see that it possible with version 2.5 but i do not see the binaries jar for javafx.
Do someone knows how to add 2.5 binaries to the javafx project?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couchbase-lite 2.x supports the Java language only on Android.  We are considering pure Java support for a future release.